# An Elementary Proof of Error Estimates for the Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I do not see how equation (4) is equal to (3) on page 2 of '[An Elementary Proof of Error Estimates for the Trapezoidal Rule](http://www.ww.ingeniousmathstat.org/sites/default/files/An_Elementary_Proof30705.pdf)'.

Here is the relevant portion of the paper:

---

...define

$$L_i = \frac{b-a}{2n}(f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i))-\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}f(t)dt.\tag{2}$$

Let $c_i$ denote the center of the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$: $c_i = \frac{(x_{i-1}+x_i)}{2}.$ Then

$$x_{i}-c_i = c_i-x_{i-1} = \frac{b-a}{2n},$$

and if we apply integration by parts "backwards," we see that we can express the error in terms of the first derivative:

$$L_i = \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}(t-c_i)f'(t)dt.\tag{3}$$

(Given (3), it is easy to apply integration by parts to show that (2) holds; it is more subtle to argue in the other direction.) If we integrate this result by parts, we can express the error in terms of the second derivative:

$$L_i = \frac{1}{2}\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}((\frac{b-a}{2n})^2-(t-c_i)^2)f''(t)dt.\tag{4}$$

---

Comment: Integrate $(4)$ by parts.

Comment: Integrate (4) by parts, differentiating the $f'$ and integrating the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same story, basically. It is fairly straightforward to get from $(4)$ to $(3)$ via integration by parts - at least knowing where you want to end up - but the other way is not so obvious. Starting at $(4)$, we find

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{b-a}{2n}\biggr)^2 & -\ (t - c_i)^2\biggr) f''(t)\,dt\\
&= \Biggl[
\frac{1}{2} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{b-a}{2n}\biggr)^2 - (t - c_i)^2\biggr) f'(t)\Biggr]_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} - \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}\bigl(-(t-c_i)\bigr)f'(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (t-c_i)f'(t)\,dt
\end{align}

since

$$(x_i - c_i)^2 = (x_{i-1} - c_i)^2 = \biggl(\frac{b-a}{2n}\biggr)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem was that I did not see that $(x_i-c_i)^2 = (x_{i-1}-c_i)^2$. The rest was clear. Quite embarrassing...